# Inicializar variables en el constructor

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Estoy inicializando variables en el constructor, pero estoy usando UserControl el tema es que cuando inicializo variables después de InitializeComponent(); Me sale un error de que no se hizo referencia al objeto, pero cuando inizializo antes de InitializeComponent(); todo funciona bien.

Donde se inicializa variables en el constructor antes o después de InitializeComponent();

```
 public partial class ucCategoria : UserControl, ICommandAction
{
    private ISaCategoria _repositoryCategoria;
    private ISaSubCategoria _repositorySubCategoria;

    public ucCategoria(ISaCategoria repositoryCategoria, ISaSubCategoria repositorySubCategoria)
    {
        _repositoryCategoria = repositoryCategoria;
        _repositorySubCategoria = repositorySubCategoria;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Hay alguna diferencia

```
public partial class ucCategoria : UserControl, ICommandAction
{
    private ISaCategoria _repositoryCategoria;
    private ISaSubCategoria _repositorySubCategoria;

    public ucCategoria(ISaCategoria repositoryCategoria, ISaSubCategoria repositorySubCategoria)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _repositoryCategoria = repositoryCategoria;
        _repositorySubCategoria = repositorySubCategoria;
    }
```

En el primer caso me funciona bien.
Nota: Estoy trabajando con Windows Forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método InitializeComponent lo crea normalmente el diseñador de formularios (o en este caso controles de usuario) de Visual Studio y tiene el código de inicialización del control de usuario, todo aquello que has definido desde el diseñador: añadir controles al control de usuario, establecer propiedades de los controles etc.

Entiendo que al realizar esta inicialización se está llamando a alguna parte del código que necesita que estas variables privadas estén inicializadas. Por eso necesitas inicializar esas variables antes.

Ojo, no es que se trate de una norma general ("debes inicializar las variables antes de llamar al InitializeComponent"), es que en tu caso es necesario hacerlo así. En otros casos podría ser necesario hacerlo después.

Si quieres saber qué código es el que está provocando el error no tienes más que depurar y seguir la pila de llamadas cuando te genere la excepción.

Comment: Asier, normalmente ponía las variables después del InitializeComponet, pero esta vez me salio un error que decía que no había hecho referencia al objeto y en el error me recomendaban un new, y cuando depuraba nunca llegaba a las veriables que tenía después del InitializeComponent, es por eso que probé poniendolas antes del InitializeComponent.

Answer (score 0):

InitializeComponent(); lo que hace es, tal como su nombre lo indica, inicializar los componentes de la IU. Usualmente debería ser luego de que retorne, y así no habrá ningún método que asigne ningún valor por defecto.

Mira esto, si es que es WPF:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245825/what-does-initializecomponent-do-and-how-does-it-work-in-wpf

Answer (score 0):

para evitar el error no seria más factible inicializar las variables en el metodo load?  asi los datos serian cargados antes de mostrarlos al usuario pero el formulario ya estaría creado así  no tendría que arrojarte error bueno  eso se me ocurre

Answer (score 0):

El componente "InitializeComponent();" dentro de la estructura C# funciona para incializar todos los parametros que contenga el formulario, sean variables o constantes, si te marca ese error es porque falta la asiganción de esos valores para ejecutar de manera correcta todos los datos, es por eso que si son valores que necesitas para un primer arranque de tu sistema debes poner todas las declaraciones de variable antes de este componente

Espero te haya funcionado, Saludos